# react heroku app my friends see only white blank page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I deployed MERN stack app on heroku - 
app link - https://real-estate-web-app.herokuapp.com

client and my friends cannot access the app; they see an only white blank page.

I can access the app in Chrome only and if I open the app in another browser it shows me a white blank page.

Please share the solution.

I tried all available solutions, but no help.

I want to share the app with client and friends so they can test it.

Comment: there is an error in the console

Comment: no error when I open this app its working fine. I have code on github - https://github.com/Rajuchoudhary/real-estate

please check if you can help me

Comment: How are you building the project?

Comment: It's MERN project. I followed all Heroku official steps to deploy the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely deploying a dev build of your app. This good for debugging but also needs `redux-devtools` installed in your browser. This is easy to see. When you look at your console (in Firefox), you see `Type Error: t is undefined`

The browser is trying to load in `redux-devtools` but it isn't defined because it doesn't exist. However you probably already have it in Chrome.

Install `redux-devtools` in firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reduxdevtools/

Or deploy your `prod` build to heroku, not `dev`. A good way to handle this is have you `dev` upload to staging/dev branch i.e. https://real-estate-web-app.staging.herokuapp.com or something like that.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Comment: Okay bro let me try